# Excel VBA to paste data to a criteria-dependent column in new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

My question is similar to several already asked, but different enough that I'm not able to apply the other solutions to my problem.

I gather data each week for 3 locations in one worksheet, and want to copy that data to a different worksheet where the data is kept as a time series by week. I can use the macro-record feature to select data for each location, but I don't know how to code for designating the correct target column range of the other worksheet, to where the data should be pasted, which is determined by the current week number.  This allows me to track/analyze the data over time.

To illustrate, I have 2 worksheets, "Summary" & "Trend", structured as follows:

```
SUMMARY Worksheet       
Week#:  5   
Prod   Loc1       Loc2        Loc3
 A    70,000     22,000      35,000 
 B    95,000     65,000     150,000 
 C   115,200    402,250     110,500 


TREND Worksheet                 

Week:       1         2      …    5      6 
     Prod
Loc1  A   84,000   112,000      70,000   ? 
      B  114,000   152,000      95,000   ? 
      C  138,240   184,320     115,200   ? 

Loc2  A   26,400    35,200      22,000   ? 
      B   78,000   104,000      65,000   ? 
      C  482,700   643,600     402,250   ?      

Loc3  A   42,000    56,000      35,000   ? 
      B  180,000   240,000     150,000   ? 
      C  132,600   176,800     110,500   ?
```

What I need is vba code that will read the week number on the "Summary" worksheet, so source data from the "Summary" worksheet is then copied to the correct corresponding column in the "Trend" worksheet. In this example, when the week# changes to 6, I need the macro to paste data from the "Summary" worksheet to the correct range in the "Trend" worksheet, based on the column header that matches the week# ("6").  I expect to do this in 3 iterations, copying & pasting data one "location" at a time.  The row of each Location's "paste" address will be constant, but I'm not exactly sure how the constant row number (per location) should be incorporated into the VBA coding either.

Justkrys...you're right...Here's some code to better understand what I'm trying to do:

```
Sub Trend_Data()
'
' Trend_Data Macro
' Copies current-week data to the corresponding Week column in Trending worksheet
' where:
'     * Defined Week # is entered in "Summary" worksheet cell L2,
'     * Corresponding Week # col hdrs (weeks 1 - 21): "Trending" worksheet, range B6:V6,
'     * Location1 target row for pasting is "Trend" worksheet row 17,
'     * Location2 target row for pasting is "Trend" worksheet row 26,
'     * Location3 target row for pasting is "Trend" worksheet row 35,
'
'
Sheets("Summary").Select
Range("D10,D12,D14,D16,D18,D20").Select
Range("D20").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Trend").Select
'
' Here is where code is required to read week number in "Summary" cell L2,
' so it can read the week number column headers in worksheet "Trending" row 6,
' to find column header "8" in cell I6.  Then it can combine Col I with row 17
' to correctly specify the range to paste Location 1 data:
'
Range("I17").Select    *'new code must determine col I is correct, row 17 is fixed target range row for pasting*
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Summary").Select
Range("E10,E12,E14,E16,E18,E20").Select
Range("E20").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Trend").Select
'
' Code for Location 2 target range selection goes here, to select col I, row26
'
Range("I26").Select       *' this is what the new code will equate to*
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Summary").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("F10,F12,F14,F16,F18,F20").Select
Range("F20").Activate
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Trend").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
'
' Code for Location 3 target range selection goes here, to select col I, row35
'
Range("I35").Select     *' Column will be determined by new code*
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

I hope this makes it easier to understand.

Comment: You have to post the code you've written if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I just hardcoded place from where we read data and place where we paste it.

```
Sub copySummary()
Dim summarySheet As Worksheet
Dim trendSheet As Worksheet
Dim weekNumber As Integer
Dim index As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set summarySheet = Sheets("Summary")
Set trendSheet = Sheets("Trend")
weekNumber = summarySheet.Cells(1, 2).Value
index = 2

For columnIdx = 1 To 3
    For rowIdx = 1 To 3
        trendSheet.Cells(rowIdx + index, weekNumber + 2).Value = summarySheet.Cells(rowIdx + 2, columnIdx + 1).Value
    Next rowIdx
    index = index + 4
Next columnIdx

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```